# on fancybox 1.2.6 close

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using fancybox 1.2.6 I want to avoid closing of fancybox when you click on the outside of the content.. But nothing is working.. can you help me with this.. and one more thing.. i am trying to trigger the fancybox close function when you submit a form..How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

set `hideOnOverlayClick` to false in your options when creating  your fancyBox. Here's an example:

```
$("a.zoom1").fancybox({
    'hideOnOverlayClick'    :       0  
});
```

To close it on the submit of your form, bind an onsubmit event to that form, and in that onsubmit function use:

```
$.fn.fancybox.close();
```

to cause the fancybox to close.

Comment: Hello Erik
i tried to close the fancybox as you said.. but i am getting some error msg "opts is undefined" and it doesn't close also...can you figure it out what it could be /

Comment: I can't figure it out based on that error; I've never closed FB with a link of my own before - I lifted that from the fb website.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the fancybox closing you can try adding these values:

```
$("a.zoom1").fancybox({
'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
'hideOnContentClick': false
                });
```

I don't know what language you want to use to close the fancybox, but to close the it from ASP.Net - add an attribute to the form submit button:

```
btnPostcode.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:parent.$.fancybox.close();");
```

Answer (score 0):

OPTS IS UNDEFINED

Today I had the task to find out why fancybox is not working on some old site, after debugging for some time, I found that lines of code that initialized the fancybox were commented.

```
 $("a.calendar_item_edit").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'frameWidth': 215,
        'frameHeight': 300
        });
```

Stripped down the comments, and all was working great.
This is fancy box 1.2.0.