# fancybox prevent close click outside of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to prevent fancybox window from closing when the user clicks outside of the
fancybox window. I am using fancybox Version: 1.3.1 on IE7, I have tried the following but I have yet to succeed. Any help is very much appreciated.

[on fancybox 1.2.6 close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115234/on-fancybox-1-2-6-close)

[jquery fancybox - prevent close on click outside of fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363806/jquery-fancybox-prevent-close-on-click-outside-of-fancybox)

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {         
 $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
  'width'           : '68%',
  'height'          : '80%',
  'autoScale'           : true,
  'transitionIn'        : 'none',
  'transitionOut'       : 'none',
  'type'            : 'iframe'
 });            
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this option :

```
'hideOnOverlayClick' : false
```

cf API doc : http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I could've sworn I had tried that before.

Comment: I just realized why it wasn't working before,  had this 'false' instead of just false no quotes.

Comment: In effect, `'false'` with quotes is a string that evaluates to `true` in a boolean context ! ^^

Comment: Whenever I try to add that option I keep getting syntax error on Dreamweaver. :/